# EntityManager.createEntity() - Strategies for showing generated ids and default values for user input

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

I have 2 entites with 1:M relationship.

```
Vehicle (Id, RetailPrice, StockOn, VehicleInfoId) and 
VehicleInfo (Id, Year, Make, Model, ICollection<Vehicle>)
```

Both Ids are user specified (strings) but because Breeze requires unique keys (even if temporary) I have to create entities with `id = breeze.core.getUuid()`.
Furthermore, Year and RetailPrice are set to 0 (Year is an int, RetailPrice is decimal).

Once I bind these entities to a "New Vehicle form" these values are immediatelly shown to the user, when in fact I want them to be blank...
What is the best way to handle this?
Some ideas I have are:

1. add additional properties (via initializer) and use those to bind on the form. Then just before the save, swap the properties.
2. "wipe out" these properties in the initializer (not the constructor)....
3. use custom KO binding handler maybe?

Is there a better way?

Here is what I have so far (using #2, but I am not sure if this is right)

/viewmodels/vehicleadd.js

```
var vehicle = ko.observable();
var viewModel = {
    title: 'Add New Vehicle',
    vehicle: vehicle,
};
return viewModel;
function activate() {
    vehicle(datacontext.createVehicle());
}
```

/services/datacontext.js

```
function init() {
    logger.debug(datacontext, 'Initializing data context...');
    return manager.fetchMetadata()
        .then(model.configureMetadataStore(manager.metadataStore))
        .then(model.applyValidators)
        //.then(loadLookups)
        .fail(initFailed);
}

function createVehicle() {
 var newVehicleInfo = manager.createEntity('VehicleInfo');
 var newVehicle = manager.createEntity('Vehicle');
 newVehicle.vehicleInfo(newVehicleInfo);

 return newVehicle;
}
```

/services/model.js

```
function configureMetadataStore(metadataStore) {
    logger.debug(model, 'Configuring metadata store...');
    extendVehicle(metadataStore);
    extendVehicleInfo(metadataStore);
}

function extendVehicle(metadataStore) {
    // --- custom constructor ---
    var vehicleCtor = function () {
        this.id = ko.observable(breeze.core.getUuid()); // must have for Breeze to work...
    };
    // --- initializer ---
    var vehicleInitializer = function (vehicle) {
        // defaults
        vehicle.id(null);                       // user to input
        vehicle.retailPrice(null);              // user to input
        vehicle.stockedOn(moment().format());   // set to current date & time
        // additional, non persisted properties
        vehicle.isBeingEdited = ko.observable(false);
        vehicle.isBeingSaved = ko.observable(vehicle.entityAspect.isBeingSaved);             
    };
    // --- register custom ctor & initializer ---
    metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor(EntityNames.Vehicle, vehicleCtor, vehicleInitializer);
}

function extendVehicleInfo(metadataStore) {
    // --- custom constructor ---
    var vehicleInfoCtor = function () {
        this.id = ko.observable(breeze.core.getUuid());
    };
    // --- initializer ---
    var vehicleInfoInitializer = function (vehicleInfo) {
        // defaults
        vehicleInfo.year = ko.observable(moment().format());
        // additional, non persisted properties
        vehicleInfo.isBeingEdited = ko.observable(false);
        vehicleInfo.isBeingSaved = ko.observable(vehicleInfo.entityAspect.isBeingSaved);
        // computed properties
        vehicleInfo.Description = ko.computed(function () {
            return vehicleInfo.year() + ' ' + vehicleInfo.make() + ' ' + vehicleInfo.model();
        });             
    };
    // --- register custom ctor & initializer ---
    metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor(EntityNames.VehicleInfo, vehicleInfoCtor, vehicleInfoInitializer);
}
```

### Update #1

After some testing, looks like #2 will not work when querying.
After (re) reading the "[Extending Entities](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities)" doc (look for "Entity creation sequence" paragraph), it specifically says that initializer function is invoked in both cases, when entity is created and in case of querying. So "wiping out" Ids, RetailPrice in initializer breaks querying and importing....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into adding a read/write Knockout (KO) computed in the initializer.

The "read" side of the computed would return blank when the value is a GUID ... or any other unique temporary value you devise.

The "write" side would (a) confirm that no other entity in cache had that key and then (b) overwrite the key with the new value. The "read" side would now display that value because it is no longer "temporary".

You're in a world of hurt if you are using these keys in any other associations; you'll have to fix them up manually ... perhaps inside your KO computed write logic.

I assume you are already prepared for the possibility that the user-entered value collides with another key on the database, entered by some other user.

I will spare you the lecture on semantic keys (as in "don't use them"); I figure some legacy database put you in this spot.

Comment: thanks! Yes I have no choice but to let user specify the key (and remote validate to insure its unique). I guess there are some cases where this is a must (think of Users where username is PK and they get to pick it)...The "write" side of this KO computed is a bit hairy already...Makes me almost not want to bind entity properties to the form but to rather have a "form centric" KO observables, then on save create entity and save it...Duplication of properties but it may be easier...:(

Comment: BTW, any suggestions for clearing out default values for properties that are primitives (e.g. integer property defaults to 0) so that shows up on the form?

Comment: Yes, don't feel that you always have to bind to an entity. Sometimes it makes more sense to have a pure "ItemViewModel" to gather the user input and then, only after it passes validation, do you create-or-update an entity. Maybe this is one of those cases.

Comment: I didn't understand your question about clearing out defaults

Comment: When you create the entity that has, for example, non nullable int property (e.g. Year), Breeze sets it to "0" (same behavior as in .NET). As soon as I bind the entity property to form field, it shows 0, but I want the field cleared so user can input it. Again I understand the reason behind the behaviour but with a lot of properties then I either have to resort to 1) adding KO computeds with read/write logic or 2) have form specific viewmodel and not create entity untill user clicks save (then create entity using forms viewmodel)...Either approach is a bit PITA, IMHO...Is there alt way?

Comment: How about writing a **[custom KO binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html)**. This is a UI issue after all and that's what bindings are for. Yours could both bind and format or you could create a formatting-only binding. Put it in your bag and apply it on whatever view suits you. Then you won't have to modify your model, write computeds, or create an "ItemViewModel" to wrap your entity.

Comment: I'm actually starting to think that a custom KO binding is the least obtrusive and perhaps easiest answer. Do share when you try it.

Comment: I agree that this is UI issue, but if I want to bind a Breeze entity to form then it is somewhat Breeze issue as well (not trying to be smart, just trying to figure out easiest way to bind entity <-> form where ID is not autocomputed). Custom KO binding may be the only solution that would minimize re-mapping (form <-> ItemViewModel <-> Entity). Thanks for all the input

Comment: @zam6ak: were able to find a solution for integer fields defaulting to '0' during binding but it should be blank instead?

Comment: @pradeep I just made extra observable and copy it as needed to model. Not a 'nice' solution, but it works.Writing a custom KO binding, as Ward mentioned, may be better, but I have not invested the time.:(